# Fluid Box jQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

Can someone please tell me why my fluid box isn't working for my photo. I've followed all of the instructions to create the code for the fluidbox, but my photo doesn't show up on the webpage. But when you click on where it is supposed to be on the webpage, it takes you to another page that has my photo in it. Here is my codes:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootswatch: Cosmo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-lightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="portfoliostyle.css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/respond/dest/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script>

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23019901-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', "bootswatch.com"]);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="imagelightbox.js"></script>
<script>
$( function()
{
    $( 'a' ).imageLightbox();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<ul class="navigation">
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>

<div class="site-wrap">
<div class="gallery">
<a class="space" href="images/spacetime.jpg" title="A Space in Time" data-fluidbox>
  <img src="images/spacetime.jpg" />
 </a>
  <a href="images/spacetime.jpg" data-fluidbox>
  <div class="fluidbox-wrap">
     <img src="images/spacetime.jpg" />
     <div class="fluidbox-ghost"></div>
    </div>
 </a>
</div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
$(function () {
// Global variables
var $fb = $('a[data-fluidbox');
vpRatio; // To store viewport aspect ratio
// Add class to all Fluidboxes
$fb.addClass('fluidbox');
// Create fluidbox modal background
$('body').append('<div id="fluidbox-overlay"></div>'); 
// Functions:
// 1. to close any opened Fluidbox
// 2. to position Fluidbox dynamically
var closeFb = function (){
    $('a[data-fluidbox].fluidbox-opened').trigger('click');
},
positionFb = function ($activeFb){
    // Get elements
    var $img = $activeFb.find('img'),
        $ghost = $activeFb.find('.fluidbox-ghost');

    // Calculate offset and scale
    var offsetY = $(window).scrollTop()-$img.offset().top+0.5*($img.data('imgHeight')*($img.data('imgScale')-1))+0.5*($(window).height()-$img.data('imgHeight')*$img.data('imgScale')),
        offsetX = 0.5*($img.data('imgWidth')*($img.data('imgScale')-1))+0.5*($(window).width()-    $img.data('imgWidth')*$img.data('imgScale')) - $img.offset().left,
        scale = $img.data('imgScale');

    // Animate wrapped elements
    // Parse integers:
    // 1. Offsets can be integers
    // 2. Scale is rounded to nearest 2 decimal places     
    $ghost.css({ 'transform':    'translate('+parseInt(offsetX*10)/10+'px,'+parseInt(offsetY*10)/10+'px)         scale('+parseInt(scale*1000)/1000+')' });
}
// The following events will force FB to close
// ... when the opqaue overlay is clicked upon
$('#fluidbox-bg').click(closeFb);
  })();

$fb.imagesLoaded().done(function (){
$fb
.wrapInner('<div class="fluidbox-wrap" />')
.find('img')
.css({ opacity: 1 })
.after('<div class="fluidbox-ghost" />');
// Listen to resize event for calculations
$(window).resize(function (){

// Get viewport aspect ratio (#1)
vpRatio = $(window).width() / $(window).height();

// Get dimensions and aspect ratios
$fb.each(function (){
    var $img = $(this).find('img'),
        $ghost = $(this).find('.fluidbox-ghost'),
        $wrap = $(this).find('.fluidbox-wrap'),
        data = $img.data();

    // Save image dimensions as jQuery object (#2)
    data.imgWidth = $img.width();
    data.imgHeight = $img.height();
    data.imgRatio = $img.width() / $img.height();

    // Resize ghost element (#3)
    $ghost.css({
        width: $img.width(),
        height: $img.height(),
        top: $img.offset().top - $wrap.offset().top,
        left: $img.offset().left - $wrap.offset().left
    });

    // Calculate scale based on orientation (#4)
    if(vpRatio > data.imgRatio) {
        data.imgScale = $(window).height()*.95 / $img.height();
    } else {
        data.imgScale = $(window).width()*.95 / $img.width();
    }
});
}).resize();
// Bind click event
$fb.click(function (e){

// Variables
var $img   = $(this).find('img'),
    $ghost = $(this).find('.fluidbox-ghost'),
    $wrap  = $(this).find('.fluidbox-wrap');

if($(this).data('fluidbox-state') == 0 || !$(this).data('fluidbox-state')) {
    // State: Closed
    // Action: Open Fluidbox
    $(this)
.data('fluidbox-state', 1)
.removeClass('fluidbox-closed')
.addClass('fluidbox-opened');
// Show overlay
$('#fluidbox-overlay').fadeIn();
// Set thumbnail image source as background image first.
// We also show the ghost element
$ghost.css({
'background-image': 'url('+$img.attr('src')+')',
opacity: 1
});
// Hide original image
$img.css({ opacity: 0 });

// Preload ghost image
var ghostImg = new Image();
ghostImg.onload = function (){ $ghost.css({ 'background-image': 'url('+$activeFb.attr('href')+')'    }   ); };
ghostImg.src = $(this).attr('href');

// Position Fluidbox
positionFb($(this));

} else {
    // State: Opened
    // Action: Close Fluidbox
    /// Switch state
$(this)
.data('fluidbox-state', 0)
.removeClass('fluidbox-opened')
.addClass('fluidbox-closed');

// Hide overlay
$('#fluidbox-overlay').fadeOut();

// Show original image
$img.css({ opacity: 1 });

// Hide ghost image
$ghost.css({ opacity: 0 });

// Reverse animation on wrapped elements
$ghost
.css({ 'transform': 'translate(0,0) scale(1)' })
.one('webkitTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd transitionend', function (){
// Wait for transntion to run its course first
$ghost.css({ opacity: 0 });
});
    }
});


</script>
```

CSS:

```
/* Navigation Menu - Background */
.navigation {
/* critical sizing and position styles */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 0;

/* non-critical appearance styles */
list-style: none;
background: #111;
}

/* Navigation Menu - List items */
.nav-item {
/* non-critical appearance styles */
width: 200px;
border-top: 1px solid #111;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav-item a {
/* non-critical appearance styles */
display: block;
padding: 1em;
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
color: white;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
color: #c74438;
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(75,20,20,0.65) 100%);
}

.site-wrap {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
 padding: 4em;
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, 
                  rgb(254,255,255) 0%,
                  rgb(221,241,249) 35%,
                  rgb(160,216,239) 100%);
background-size: 200%;
}

.name {
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
right:40%;
}

h3{
text-align: center;
top: 65%;
}

/* Nav Trigger */
.nav-trigger {
/* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
position: absolute;
clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
/* critical positioning styles */
position: fixed;
left: 15px; top: 15px;
z-index: 2;

/* non-critical apperance styles */
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px'   viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/>    <rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
background-size: contain;
}

/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
transition: left 0.2s;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
left: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
left: 200px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

 body {
/* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Additional non-critical styles */

h1, h3, p {
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

code {
padding: 2px;
background: #ddd;
}

/* Micro reset */
*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-       box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

/* Image Lightbox Galley */

a[data-fluidbox] {
background-color: #eee;
border: none;
cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

a[data-fluidbox].fluidbox-opened {
cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
}

a[class^='float'] {
margin: 1rem;
margin-top: 0;
width: 33.33333%;
}

a.float-left {
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
}

a.float-right {
float: right;
margin-right: 0;
}

a[data-fluidbox] img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
opacity: 0;
max-width: 100%;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

#fluidbox-overlay {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
cursor: pointer;
cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 500;
}
.fluidbox-wrap {
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 400;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fluidbox-opened .fluidbox-wrap {
    z-index: 600;
}
.fluidbox-ghost {
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center center;
     position: absolute;
     transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.space img{
height: 25%;
width: 50%
}
```

Comment: Hey there! :) Plugin author chiming in here. I would recommend using the latest JS and CSS files from the [latest release](https://github.com/terrymun/Fluidbox) — also, it helps to create a minimal example of your issue so we can help you with the troubleshooting.